# Downgrade Xamarin from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android, downgrade

I am having trouble with the AXML designer panel taking a long time to load.  Per the advice [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/77992/axml-layout-designer-inside-visual-studio-keeps-loading-forever), I am trying to downgrade to Xamarin 4.1.2.18.  Apparently this is easy enough when you are using the whole registered Xamarin account whatnot, but as I installed this through the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition installer, I did not have to register for an Xamarin account, nor did I get to select a specific version of Xamarin to use.  Has anyone successfully downgraded Xamarin from Visual Studio 2015 Community?

Comment: Did you try just creating an account and then downloading the SDK you want to downgrade to as described [here](https://kb.xamarin.com/customer/portal/articles/1699777-how-do-i-downgrade-to-an-older-version-)?

Comment: You can reach out contact@xamarin.com if you couldn't find previous installers

Comment: What steps would one need to take to reproduce the issue? If Visual Studio is hanging, consider [filing a bug report](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/howto-file-bug/) with the [call stack of Visual Studio's main thread](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/troubleshooting/vs-callstack/), steps to reproduce, and [version info](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/troubleshooting/questions/version-logs/).